# Windows Server 2003 image to vmWare ESXI server

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi

I want to move Windows Server 2003 to vmWare ESXI server. Is there any tool to do Windows image ant move to new vmware ESXI server?

Is this impossible and maybe have anyone info about this how to do? Or some tutorials. I'm trying to find anything on google, but event no luck

Answer (score 4):

vmware converter is free, and capable of cloning it. Stop any databases and such before migrating, and uninstall drivers, raid tools etc on the newly cloned virtual server.

Comment: We've run the VMware Converter on six or seven servers so far.  Let the server boot once and detect the new drivers, then install the VMware tools and let those drivers install before you start the services on the server.

Comment: **Important Pro Tip** - You should edit the disk config on when using VMWare converter and adjust each Partition on your machine to be it's own VMWare HDD when possible. Unlike a physical server you can grow Virtual Disks at will as needed....as long as the disk doesn' have three partitions back to back :)  The only exception that I would consider typically would be if it is a file server and needed the drive letters to host shares or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

Like @3molo stated you can use VMware Converter.  What you're doing is called a p2v (physical to virtual).  You can get the converter and read about how to use it at [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/).  We used it at my last job and it works quite well.  Just make sure you follow @3molo's other advice (databases, drivers, etc).